# Viewcontroller is not recognizing my variables?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, swift2

Having another problem .

Why am I not able to see my variables here ? I cannot see my "arr" variable and "dict" . I want to use them in some properties with "." but when the program is not recognizing my variables ? Can you please help me? What am I doing wrong.

[image: This is the pic]

it says expected declaration but I already declared it ??

```
import UIKit
import Foundation

class data: UIView {

    let item1 = Set(["Egg"])
    var chosenItem = Set(["Egg", "Rice"])

    var arr : Array<Dictionary<String,Any>> = []

    //var dict: Dictionary<String,Any> = [:]
    var dict : Dictionary<String,Any> = [:]

    dict.
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you need to access your variables in a function. You will need to call the function from somewhere though. Try this:

```
import UIKit
import Foundation

class data: UIView {

    let item1 = Set(["Egg"])
    var chosenItem = Set(["Egg", "Rice"])

    var arr : Array<Dictionary<String,Any>> = []

    //var dict: Dictionary<String,Any> = [:]
    var dict : Dictionary<String,Any> = [:]

    func myFunction() {
        // Use your variables here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A class is compromised of variables and functions. Make sure you're using your variables within your own custom written functions or existing ones. For instance try doing what you're doing but inside of your `viewDidLoad()` method.